# Doctrine filters for order by sentence

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is there something similar to [doctrine filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html) which allows to add order by sentences to any outcoming query? I need to append the order by sentence to all the database queries performed under any request with method get.

Update: Take in consideration I never know the sort criteria, that's up to the user, so defining @OrderBy annotation solves the problem partially.

Update2: Perhaps it is possible to achieve this by modifying the ClassMetadata param in the filter body, just I cant realize which property does the job

```
class FilterTenant extends SQLFilter {

    protected $reader;
    protected $userGroups;
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Gets the SQL query part to add to a query.
     *
     * @param ClassMetaData $targetEntity
     * @param string $targetTableAlias
     *
     * @return string The constraint SQL if there is available, empty string otherwise.
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if (empty($this->reader)) {
            return '';
        }
        $DeletedMarkerAnn = $this->reader->getClassAnnotation(
            $targetEntity->getReflectionClass(),
            'AplicacionBaseBundle\\Filters\\Tenant'
        );

        if (!$DeletedMarkerAnn) {
            return '';
        }

    //$targetEntity->what?
    }

    public function setAnnotationReader(Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a default sort to a relation, as described in the doc http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby

Comment: thing is: I never know which one will be the ordering criteria, that is why I am looking for something like a filter, so I can add extra info to the sql query. Anyway thanks